# Splitting a string into a list (but not separating adjacent numbers) in Python

Tags: python, string, list

For example, I have:

```
string = "123ab4 5"
```

I want to be able to get the following list:

```
["123","ab","4","5"]
```

rather than list(string) giving me:

```
["1","2","3","a","b","4"," ","5"]
```

Comment: what are the rules? [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find one or more adjacent digits (`\d+`), or if that fails find non-digit, non-space characters (`[^\d\s]+`).

```
>>> string = '123ab4 5'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d+|[^\d\s]+', string)
['123', 'ab', '4', '5']
```

If you don't want the letters joined together, try this:

```
>>> re.findall('\d+|\S', string)
['123', 'a', 'b', '4', '5']
```

Comment: You don't need to have the `\s` there, and you shouldn't shadow built-ins using `string` as a variable name. - Also, your script does not catch the space character.

Comment: @InbarRose `string` isn't a builtin as such (it's a deprecated module for those purposes) - and `import string` is rarely used... it's more used as `from string import` where those are constants or maketrans

Comment: @john - you are correct, my apologies. it seems i also misread the question. you have the correct solution to this problem. :) +1

Comment: Until it's no longer a module included with Python at all, I think it still probably shouldn't be used as a variable.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Quick question before I have to go (OP here). How would I go about splitting the string in the middle into "a","b"?

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are definitely easier. If you want something far less straightforward, you could try something like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = "123ab4 5"
>>> result = [''.join(list(v)) for _, v in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x.isdigit())]
>>> result = [x for x in result if x not in string.whitespace]
>>> result
['123', 'ab', '4', '5']
```

Comment: "If you want something far less straightforward..." -- Love it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Haha, wanted to make sure that everyone knew it was a horrible solution (although that much was clear :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
>>> [el for el in re.split('(\d+)', string) if el.strip()]
['123', 'ab', '4', '5']
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman true, but since given the question, it's ambigious as to whether they should be or not....

Answer (score 0):

you can do a few things here, you can

**1. iterate the list and make groups of numbers as you go, appending them to your results list.**

not a great solution.

**2. use regular expressions.**

implementation of 2:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "123ab4 5"
>>> re.findall('\d+|[^\d]', s)
['123', 'a', 'b', '4', ' ', '5']
```

you want to grab any group which is at least 1 number `\d+` or any other character.

**edit**

John beat me to the correct [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457869/1561176) first. and its a wonderful [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457869/1561176).

i will leave this here though because someone else might misunderstand the question and look for an answer to what i thought was written also. i was under the impression the OP wanted to capture only groups of numbers, and leave everything else individual.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the split you want:

```
re.findall(r'\d+|[a-zA-Z]+', "123ab4 5")

['123', 'ab', '4', '5']
```